# I am trying to count the age of the open tickets in a row context and categorise them as open <4 days, open>7 days etc

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to count the age of the open tickets in a row context and categorise them as open <4 days, open>7 days etc.

```
Level    <=4days    >5days
Level1   30         5
Level2   40         20
```

Expecting something like this. Trying to use the below logic.

```
Open Ticket _Age = 
IF(
   SELECTEDVALUE( Incident'[closedate]) = BLANK(),
    DATEDIFF((Incident[contactdate]),(Calendartable[MonthEnding]),DAY)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the OpenTicketAge variable to calculate the difference in days between today and the contactdate for tickets that have a blank closedate.

Then with the SWITCH , I categorize these ages into "<=4 days", "5-7 days", and ">7 days" based on the calculated age :

```
Open Ticket Age Category = 
VAR OpenTicketAge = 
    IF(
        ISBLANK(SELECTEDVALUE(Tickets[closedate])), 
        DATEDIFF(TODAY(), SELECTEDVALUE(Tickets[contactdate]), DAY)
    )
RETURN
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        OpenTicketAge <= 4, "<=4 days",
        OpenTicketAge >= 5 AND OpenTicketAge <= 7, "5-7 days",
        OpenTicketAge > 7, ">7 days",
        "Not Open"
    )
```

Comment: Hi Amira, Thanks. But it didn't work.

Comment: Can you please share more info about your model? tables ? some data ?

Comment: Hi Amira ,I am trying to calculate the age of open tickets at the end of the month OpenCaseAge = 

 var endOfPrevMonth = EOMONTH( MAX( Calendar[Date] ), -1)
RETURN

    CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Calendar'[Date]),
     ISBLANK(Incident[closedate] &&
    endOfPrevMonth >=Incident[ContactDate]&& endOfPrevMonth<=Incident[closedate]) 
   
       ) This is gives true instead of count  , wondering how can I fix this

Comment: Yes but please share some of your data.